# Skewed response variable LM

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, data-transformation, model, skewness

I have a positive asymmetric response variable in a regression model. One of the assumptions about linear model is that the stochastic component of the model is normally distributed. If I have a skewed response but my residuals are normally distributed could I use the linear model or I have to choose or a transformation or a GLM?

Comment: Could you clarify the distinctions you are making between "stochastic component," "response," and "residuals"?  I think the answer to your question may rest on understanding these.

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please read it. If it isn't what you're want / you still have a question afterwords, come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.